# Databricks for visual studio code is not showing the existing databricks repos and creating a new repo throws authentication error

Tags: databricks, vscode-extensions

Databricks for visual studio code is not showing Databricks repos and when creating a new repo It throws an authentication error.

Error:
error_code: PERMISSION_DENIED, message: Missing Git provider credentials. Go to User settings > Git Integration to add your personal access token.

Github Enterprise Access Token is added to Databricks Git Integration plugin. cloned my-repo to Databricks Repo using the access token.

Comment: Databricks is creating a repo under Repo/someone@example.com/
But it should be Repos/someone@example.com/

missing S. Will it causing the error?

Comment: Could you create a ticket under https://github.com/databricks/databricks-vscode/issues/new so we can track and fix the issue?